# Change value in highcharts navigator handle

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use highcharts in javascript. Now, if I click in navigator's handle the date change in 1 day, but I would like the change was more days, but I don't find/know the parameter in highcharts.

Thank you everybody.

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo and describe your requirement in more details?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/ede69mxr/

Isn't mine but the example is perfect. When you move the navigator, the days change one by one, and I want that with each movement the days change two by two.

Comment: That value is hardcoded in the core [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/e767da738d3677ffdd40b11ff4312b39d0e56717/js/parts/Scroller.js#L653-L660). So it's not one day, but 20% of the current, visible, range.